# IF Formula HELP. Nesting

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, nested

I need help with a formula..The situation is..

Daily rate for painting is:

- $100 per day for 3 or less days of painting
- $90 for each day beyond the first 3.

For example, if you paint for 5.5 days, you get paid $100 for each of the first three days and $90 for each of the remaining 2.5 days giving a total of $525.

How can I put this as a IF formula?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that needs an IF at all. You could do this:

```
=MAX(0,(A1-3))*90+(MIN(3,A1)*100)
```

Subtract 3 from the value in A1. Any result greater than zero you will be multiplied by 90. Any result less than zero will be ignored. Then work out what is smaller: A1 or 3. Whichever is the smallest will be multiplied by 100.

Answer (score 0):

assuming the days is in column A

```
IF(A1>3, 300+(A1-3)*90, A1*100)
```